# SqlDataSource : adding user session in parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am using a datagridview with edit and delete auto generated.

I would like to use in my select statement my session user as a parameter.

When I do that, it doesn't display anything.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT .... WHERE AgentID = @UserID">

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name ="Session['UserID']"></asp:Parameter>
</SelectParameters>
```

How I declare my session: I tried it and it's working well.

```
   Session["UserID"] = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asp sessions parameter:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="randomname" Type="string" SessionField="UserID" DefaultValue="your default value"/>
```